# Make SharePoint Top Navigation Multi lingual

Tags: custom-masterpage, top-link-bar

I have sharepoint navigation in SP 2013, I need to make it multi lingual, I am facing the problem of adding links, and they are multi lingual, but there is only one hyperlink that's unable to be in 2 languages, how do we make the top nav as multi lingual?

thanks